# nodered hotkeys not working in azure web app

Tags: node.js, azure-web-app-service, node-red

I have a nodejs application (fork of https://github.com/node-red/node-red) which is running on an Azure WebApp. The Application is working fine if i run it on my local computer. If the application is runnin on a AzureWeb App (Git deployment) the hotkeys do no longer work (i can not delete or copy the nodes on the website)

The NodeJs Version is the exact same on both environments. I have no clue why the hotkeys do not work as soon as i deploy the application to a Azure WebApp?

Comment: Given all the interaction with the Node-RED editor is in the browser, where it's deployed should have absolutely impact if everything is same.

Comment: I already redeployed everything multiple times, the same sourcecode with the same commands to build runes fine on a windows 10 machine and on a raspbian.

Answer (score 1):

Node-RED uses the WebSocket protocol. So my guess is that you have not enabled **Web sockets** for your application on Azure.

To enable that, please see below steps:

1. Go to the [Azure portal](http://portal.azure.com).
2. Click Application settings in the **SETTINGS** menu.
3. Set **Web sockets** to **On**.
4. Click **Save**.

[image]